# How to use a revision control system in general

Tags: git, svn, version-control, revision

I am planning to create projects which will get a bit bigger than my projects before, so I thought it would be good to use a revision control system like svn or git to keep track of all changes, experiment a little bit with new functionalities in code without risks and so on.

Now (besides the question whether I should use svn or git), I am asking myself "how to use" such a system in general.

Up to now, I found vocabulary like *trunk*, *tags* and *branches* (The word *merging* appears often in that context). But I am not really sure how to really work with them. *Tags* seem to be something like release versions (if not please correct me), but I do not know what really belongs in the *trunk* or in a *branch*; when to use what etc..

During my researches, I also found a recommendation that you should generally create a folder structure with the sub-folders branches, tags and trunk for a new project. Would you also recommend this? Or should I handle the source-code of a project a different way?

Can somebody try to explain this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The topic of version control systems is probably a bit too large to teach as part of a Q&A site like Stack Overflow. You're certainly welcome to ask questions about them, but "can anyone tell me all I need to know about them" is probably not the right place.

If you're interested in distributed version control systems, since you've mentioned git, you should take a look at [hginit.com](http://hginit.com). While the site describes [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com), most, if not all, holds true for git as well.

As for the recommendation to create those folders, that depends entirely on the version control system you decide to use.

Subversion uses folder-level "copies" to create branches. Think of it as having multiple copies of your project on disk at the same time, and that Subversion allows you to merge changes from one folder to another and keeps track of what you have merged, when, and in which direction.

For DVCS', that isn't necessary, since branches are done in a different way, and thus you don't need those directories.

The vocabulary you have listed can be summed up as follows (note that since I use Mercurial, I might be colored by their use in that system):

- **Trunk** - Your main development line. If you didn't have source control, this is where you would work all the time.
- **Tags** - A tag is a lightweight marker, think of it as a postit note, that you affix to a certain version of your project so that you later can answer the question "Hmm, I wonder what all the source files looked like when I released version 1.0"
- **Branches** - A branch is a parallell universe copy of your project, possibly with changes. For instance, when you released that 1.0 version, you might create that tag, but you might also create a branch. Then, on trunk, you would start working towards version 2.0 or 1.1, and if you need to release a hotfix of 1.0 to fix bugs, you would then do those fixes on that 1.0 branch.
- **Merging** - When you have multiple branches, you can ask your version control system to help you get changes done on one branch into another by merging them (the changes or the branches, this differs from system to system.)
- **Changeset/revision** - Nearly synonymous, means a set of changes you committed at the same time. It might be to fix a particular bug, or add a particular feature. A changeset can contain changes to many files, and even new files, or removal of files no longer needed.

The [Wikipedia article on Revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) also has quite a lot of useful information.

The [Mercurial glossary](http://selenic.com/hg/help/glossary) also lists a fair number of terms and their usage in Mercurial, and much of that information is true for many version control systems.

---

Anyway, here's a typical (for me anyway) way to do a project.

- You create the initial project repository, with just the main branch (trunk in Subversion, default in Mercurial, master? I think in git)
- You then start working on your project, and you commit regularly, you build up a nice list of changesets
- At some point you are ready to release version 1.0, so you create that tag, and you create a branch at that point named "1.0", and then you release your software
- You then continue working, towards version 1.1 or 2.0, depending
- At some point you have a list of bugs that have been found in 1.0 by customers
- You fix those bugs in trunk/default/master, so that the next big version at least has those bugfixes, then you merge the changes back into 1.0
- When all known bugs in 1.0 have been fixed, you tag that as 1.01, and release that
- And back to work on 2.0
- When 2.0 is ready to release, you tag and branch again, etc.

This is just one way to do it, there are many. People will tell you their preferred way if you ask them and I won't say my way is right.

Comment: Thank you that you took the time to answer :) I do not really search everything about version control systems that would be too much for a site like Stack Overflow ;) I just wanted to know some "basics" like the trunk tag branches thing (with other words how the development process in general goes); so something were to start "understanding" and continuing my researches regarding those systems

Comment: I've edited in a few more details. Note that there probably isn't a right way to do this, but there are plenty of bad ways to do this, the good ways are just good in different ways. I suggest you first decide if you want to use a centralized version control system or a distributed one (ie. Subversion vs. Mercurial/git), and then read up on how they each work. The devil is in the details. My advice, however, is to go with a DVCS, and since I use Mercurial, of course Mercurial is the best one there is :)

Comment: "few more details" o_O. Btw, +1 for the answer itself and for mentioning mercurial as a start point.

Comment: Thank you :) This answer helps me a lot and I think I have a good idea how a vcs "works" :)

Answer (score 5):

You can start examining http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control and http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Also `trunk-tag-branch` is a little obsolete schema, used in svn. DSCMs (mercurial, git) have native support for branches and tags so you don't need to create those directories explicitly.

Comment: Obsolete?  No, it still works perfectly well.  Subversion is alive and well.  Creating those directories isn't such a great hardship.

Comment: I think perhaps he meant that the usage of those directories should not be carried over into DVCS', since they don't use folder-level copies as branches.

Comment: @duffymo: yes, I meant exactly what Lasse V. Karlsen said above.

Comment: I get it.  The OP didn't say 'I must use a distributed version control system.'

Comment: @duffymo: he must not. But nowadays I don't see any benefits of using svn instead of mercurial and git (which are definitely better). Do you know any?

Comment: In his context, I would have to say no, but if he's either used to Subversion (he doesn't sound to be), or working in an environment where they already use it (he doesn't sound to be doing that either), then there might be some benefits. If he's on his own, and free to choose, I would have to say go with a DVCS, hands down no contest.

Comment: Sure, Subversion still works just fine.  Lots of hosting solutions on the web use it, as do open source projects.  And so does my employer.  I haven't see a wholesale switch to distibuted SCM projects.  Subversion is still very much in use, but I don't have market share numbers to quantify it either way.  I doubt that anyone else here does, either.  I have a choice here on my personal system, and I'm still using Subversion.  Works fine.  I don't see any 'hands down' benefit for managing my own stuff in a distributed way.

Comment: @duffymo: well, just try mercurial then when you have some spare time. Once I did that - I never have chosen svn in the project I could chose used scm. Nowadays lots of hostings also have git/hg installed, as well as a lot of opensourced projects moved to git (thanks to github). Not a subject for discussing, but personally I'll never suggest anyone to even look at svn anymore.

Comment: @duffymo: That's part of my point. There's nothing wrong or bad with Subversion at all, it's a very good version control system. It all comes down to which features you need. There are things that Subversion can do that Mercurial/git can't, and vice versa. However, my *opinion* is that Mercurial gives more bang for the buck :) But I'm biased on that. The important part is to read up on the different systems, and decide yourself.

Comment: Fair enough, Lasse and zerkms.  I'll make it a point to check out Mercurial.

Comment: +1 for http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on [Lasse V. Karlsen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773675/how-to-use-a-revision-control-system-in-general/5773704#5773704):

- With respect to **learning to use revision control**, you probably should take a look at "Related questions" that Stackoverflow found for you.
  In my opinion [The Git Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html) by Tom Preston-Werner of GitHub nicely teaches how and why one should use (distributed) version control system (describing how DVCS such as Git *could* have been created).
- About **branching model**: if the version control system you are using supports lightweight branches, and it can merge branches well and fast, you usually use *two kinds of branches* in typical workflow:

  - **long-lived branches** such as 'master' or 'main' or 'stable' (aka 'trunk') where current work towards new release goes, 'next' or 'devel' or 'unstable' is where you put experimental work, 'maint' or 'maintenance' is where bugfixes to last release go.
  - **topic branches** - when starting work on new feature it is better to put it in separate short-lived and usually not published branch.  This way you can work on some experimental new feature without destabilizing other work; it allows to work in parallel on many unrelated features.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The Subversion [Red Bean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) book has a nice discussion about the topic.

[Pragmatic Version Control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616657) is a fine book, too.

Comment: That pragmatic book is a bit old, if he's going to read up on Subversion he should at least pick something that covers 1.5 or newer, with all the new merge changes.